# Uncaught exception 'PharException' в PHP 5.6 на Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Не так давно занимаюсь администрированием сервера, возникла такая ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '__HALT_COMPILER();  
must be declared in a phar' in /var/www/site.ru/public_html/addons/geoip/geoip2.phar:8  
Stack trace:  
#0 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/addons/geoip/geoip2.phar(8): Phar::mapPhar('geoip2.phar')  
#1 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/includes/geo.php(2): require_once('/var/www/site...')  
#2 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/content/pages/account.php(4): require_once('/var/www/site...')  
#3 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/classes/content.php(55): require('/var/www/site...')  
#4 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/classes/content.php(88): Content->add('pages/account')  
#5 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/includes/engine.php(48): Content->page('account')  
#6 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/classes/engine.php(17): require_once('/var/www/site...')  
#7 /var/www/site.ru/public_html/index.php(8): Engine::start()
#8 {main} thrown in /var/www/site.ru/public_html/addons/geoip/geoip2.phar on line 8
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить проблему?

Версия *PHP*: **5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, связано с [этой ошибкой](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/273).

если установленный у вас пакет `php5-xcache` содержит эту ошибку, попробуйте его деинсталлировать:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove php5-xcache
```

Comment: Проблема исчезла, но на что это повлияет? Нет ли способов устранения проблемы без удаления xcache?

Comment: @Cript: *на что это повлияет* — на невозможность использования `xcache` (если, конечно, он у вас вообще используется). *нет ли способов* — способов, вероятно, много. удаление пакета, содержащего код с ошибкой — самый простейший.